# Using XML to store data

Tags: android, xml, storing-data

I am looking to use an XML file to store the data my Android app generates. With that in mind, I have two questions for the community:

1. Is `XML` the best way to store data on Android and most efficient in cases where data may be added or altered every second or less then a second.
2. If `XML` is indeed the best for the scenario described in #1, how do I go about setting it up?

Comment: I usually use JSON to implement the communication between my app and the DB.

Comment: Why would you choose XML as database ??? SQLite database is the natural (and probably mostly used) database in Android apps. Any reason why you are not using SQLite?

Comment: How would you do all the CRUD operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1.) Is XML the best way to database data on android and most efficient in cases where data may be added or altered every second or less then a second.

Definitely not.

> 2.) If XML is indeed the best for the scenario described in #1, how do I go about setting it up?

If you plan to store data just locally, the best way would be SQLite which works as a local database on every device.

If you later plan to synchronize this data with a central database, you may do this asynchronously within an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` which would run periodically, but writing each second into a XML file is a bad idea as far as performance goes.

It's probably also a bad idea synchronizing a remote database at each insert/modification/deletion operation as if you had many users you could collapse the remote database.

I think the best approach is (as previously said) having a local database where you would store that data, and implement a webservice in the remote side if needed and use it to periodically synchronize both databases.

Answer (score 0):

I would use JSON over XML and I would highly consider using [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) from Google. You maybe want to consider writing directly to a database with it's own structure and use transactions and sets. Is there are reason you want to go through JSON/XML?

Comment: Why would you recommend GSON over Jackson for instance. OP is asking for performance and GSON is by far one of the slowest JSON libs out there. See for instance: http://blaazinsoftwaretech.blogspot.dk/2013/08/jackson-2-vs-gson-performance-comparison.html - GSON is a nice wrapper for parsing JSON, but it's slow...

Comment: Of course it is "slow", but there is no more information given. His question is more architectural in nature than performance. However, I also suggested he not using JSON and just write straight to the DBs with transactions.

Comment: Actually whizzle, if you read the original question I state the data needs to be stored at most every second if not faster.

Comment: Then you should use a real database structure and use transactions. Depending on how "fast" you need this even consider storing information in memory and batch processing it to the database. Again, there's very little context.

Comment: @whizzle I guess I was just pointing out that you made a recommendation based on, well nothing ;-)

Comment: @Darwind, I gave a recommend based upon his requirements. The choices given were XML or JSON. I gave the better choice of the 2 and then told him straight database works was even better. And then ask why he chose XML or JSON. I guess I'm just pointing out that perhaps you shouldn't be answering questions posed to OP by not answering them. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

XML is one of the worst ideas to keep local data in Android.

Most common used is SQLite available on the Android platform, but it all depends on what data and how you want to use.

In many mobile applications you don't need the relational database for one of the following reasons:

- You have no relational data (i.e. settings) => no point in making relational tables with 1 record each
- You have small, and dynamically changed data (like cache for downloaded content)
- You don't need to search for data (using indexes etc.)

What alternatives can be used?
Shared preferences - simple key/value storage of primitive objects
Data serialization - for your consideration - binary (native java), JSON, parcelable (can be combined with the shared preferences)

For most of my app I'm currently using the binary serialization for "local storage". 
 - It's fast enough (usually much faster than starting the local SQLite engine)
 - It's extremely easy and quick to implement, especially when you are using it for json/xml downloaded data parsed to POJO objects. All you need to do is just put "extends serializable" and put few lines of code to serialize/deserialize whole structure
 - You can use those same classes for keeping data locally and communication with backend

Of course -  it all depends from the situation - if you want to keep locally log of data from some sensor, or allow others apps to use this data, have to quick filter 1k+ records, or you really like to write few hundreds lines of code SQLite will be the best option for you. But most of mobile applications has no clear reason to use the relational (and trust me - not perfect one) engine.

Comment: I guess I know what you mean, but still - it's rather funny to say "XML is one of the worst ideas to keep local data in Android" and then suggest "shared preferences" - which is actually a local XML file...

Comment: Simply - I don't see any advangages of XML serialization. If some one wants to use some human readible format - let's use JSON (faster), binary serialization gives more speed with minimum work needed to implement it. If you have somre "real" data - let's use the SQLite - for every scenario I can imagine - there is a better option.

Comment: Please, read my comment again. I am far from questioning your main point. Rather, I was amused by the fact that you dis XML, and AT THE SAME TIME praise shared preferences. Which is a wrapper around an XML file... :-)

Comment: You are rigth ;) as I wrote - everything depends on kind of data you have to keep in your application