# android, storing data on web server without database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

is there a way to store information (strings, numbers, booleans) on a webserver without using a database(mysql, sqlite, etc...) in android?

similar to how vb can read/write to a access "database" by only using a single file.
Thank you

Comment: This has an answer for your question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021968/using-xml-to-store-data)

Comment: Try Firebase. It's free and lots of tutorials.

Comment: Of course that is possible. Just store it in files.

Comment: what do you guys think of using sqlite, exporting it as a csv and uploading it? then download it when you want to sync it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write into json file as save it in server. For best approach, it is recommended to use database. Easier to do CRUD operations.

Answer (score -1):

For store information into android application u can use SharedPreferences.[about SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Or ,You can used a lib for store all data [ObjectCache](https://github.com/iainconnor/ObjectCache)

Comment: SharedPreferences aren't on a web server

Comment: Sorry ,I thinks u need to store into local data .For web server , u can used firebase database https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: But firebase isn't a web-server. It is only a database.

Comment: How to call web-server plz check this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NFwF7L-YA8

Comment: Like I said, web-server != "database"